# acesses IIS deployed website from android mobile browser

Tags: android, asp.net, web-services

I make a app which get data from local server through Web Service ( developed in asp.net 4.0 )
. The application works fine on emulator ( get and send data properly) but when i use app on mobile which is on same network . then error comes . And i also try to open website through mobile browser it also not working . 
where is he problems ? is there some setting which should be done to acsses the webservice through mobile ?

Comment: Firewall config? Also is it your own machine/network or some organizational (may need additional steps in later case - check with admins of your network).

Comment: where's your IIS located? Local or organization server ?

Comment: Also check the ip of your mobile device, the problem is definitely routing and ip-oriented

Answer (score 0):

I find answer . The problem is that : the 80 port is not opened in firewall. I open that port and it works fine .